# LDAP Login with two OUs (or sub OU) for Oracle APEX

Tags: ldap, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to use LDAP for my oracle apex application, I already have setup a current LDAP which refers to the base OU in the LDAP, but we also have another OU or a sub-ou, for a second set of users, I need them to login to my application as well - I know the host and port and such, and I know I have to set the Use Exact Distinguished String to no and provide a search filter (Please let me know if this is wrong), but I don't know how I can reference both the sub OU and the normal OU. Can anyone please give an example of a search string with a regular OU and a second OU or a sub-OU for LDAP for Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, it's ok to `Use Exact Distinguished Name : No`, and set a `search base` instead.

You can specify only *one* search base, this setting is used so that the backend actually searches down the DIT *under* that base. But it's probably not an issue unless having a huge directory, you just need to set the common "container" for your users, and not necessarily an  organizational unit, any entry located "above" in the tree.

For example, if you have these 2 OUs : `ou=accounts,dc=example,dc=com` and `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`, you would set `dc=example,dc=com` as the base.

Looking at DN's, you would only take the longest common part, starting from the right (it's pretty much like in the DNS hierarchy).